# Laravel Input::old is an array as a string

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

In my form im outputting some json or a string of data that is an array from Input::old('tags') the problem I'm having is being able to test it and see if it is json and if it is do a foreach loop and put the tag attribute is an array then implode the array and output it in an input field.

```
[{"id":112,"tag":"corrupti","tagFriendly":"corrupti","created_at":"2015-07-20 00:05:28","updated_at":"2015-07-20 00:05:28","pivot":{"question_id":60,"tag_id":112,"created_at":"2015-07-20 00:05:28","updated_at":"2015-07-20 00:05:28"}},{"id":9,"tag":"placeat","tagFriendly":"placeat","created_at":"2015-07-20 00:05:23","updated_at":"2015-07-20 00:05:23","pivot":{"question_id":60,"tag_id":9,"created_at":"2015-07-20 00:05:28","updated_at":"2015-07-20 00:05:28"}}]
```

So my output should look like this

```
'corrupti, placeat, etc...'
```

Could someone help me get the desired result following the steps I just outlined

This code doesn't work but it's what I kinda need to happen. is_array is always false

```
<?php
    $tags = Input::old('tags');
    if(is_array($tags)) {
        foreach ($tags as $tag) {
            $tags[] = $tag->tag;
        }
        $tags = implode(', ', $tags);   
    }                       
?>
```

Comment: json_decode will return an object containing the array so how you have it now is_array should be returning false.

Comment: it returns false even if I don't decode it

Comment: yes because it's not seeing an array. you need to extract the array from the object. try $obj = json_decode($tags); print_r($obj[0]); see what that shows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go.

```
$tags = json_decode(Input::old('tags'), true); // decode json input as an array

if (is_array($tags)) {
    foreach ($tags as $key=>$value) {
        $tags[$key] = $value['tag'];
    }
    $tags = implode(', ', $tags);
    echo $tags;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_map to extract the tag property from the object.

```
<?php
$jsonObject = json_decode(Input::old('tags'));
if(is_array($jsonObject)) {
    $onlyTags = array_map(function($item) { return $item->tag; },$jsonObject);
    print implode(",", $onlyTags);
}
```

Comment: the part where it goes is_array($jsonObject) return false so the code doesn't get past the if statement

Comment: show us the output of this thing: `dd(Input::old('tags'));`

Answer (score 1):

Try adding true to json_decode.

```
json_decode($tags, true);
```

According to the docs that should return an associative array. 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

is_array might not work with associative arrays with a key/value pair. Try replacing is_array with this function:

```
function is_associate_array($array)
{
    return $array === array_values($array);
}
```

So:

```
if(is_associate_array(json_decode($tags, true))) {

}
```

Comment: It still returns false when you test if it is an array

Comment: don't believe is_array will work. please look at my edit.

Comment: your function `is_associate_array` do the opposite thing. it should be named  as `is_not_associate_array`. BTW `is_array` will work fine. the only reason why `is_array(json_decode(Input::old('tags'), true))` not works is that `Input::old('tags')` - is not a json string